# Unable to Show Web API Data in a listview in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a cross platform app in Xamrin with Visual Studio 2017. Have made a simple form for testing with just one listview.
I am trying to GetData from my WebAPI and show it in a listview. 
I checked my web API end points using Postman and its working perfectly alright. But my listview does not show any data . Trying desperately to find out what is it that is creating the problem .
My code from XAML , .CS file and View Model is as shown below.

**VIEW MODEL CODE:**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

{

 public class ItemDetailsClass

    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
    }

 public ObservableCollection<ItemDetailsClass> ItemsListMain
    {
        get { return _itemsListMain; }
        set
        {
            _itemsListMain = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

public async Task <ObservableCollection<ItemDetailsClass>> GetAsync()

    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);
        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ItemDetailsClass>>
    (json); 
    return taskModels;

    }

    private async Task InitaializeDataAsync()

    {
        ItemsListMain = await GetAsync();

    }

   public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitaializeDataAsync();
    }
}
```

**XAML CODE:**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>

</ContentPage.BindingContext>



 <ListView

    x:Name="MyListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsListMain}"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsVisible="True">


<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding ItemCode}" TextColor="Black"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Page.Cs CODE**

```
  MainViewModel myViewModel = new MainViewModel();
  MyListView.BindingContext = myViewModel;
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here????? Its been quite a long time since I have been trying to figure out why my listview is not showing my data.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: i can not see any issue in your code, can you post declaration of this variable ItemsListMain

Comment: why you have seperate view model for ListView ????
  MyListView.BindingContext = myViewModel;

Comment: Can you include the complete VM class? Where is `ItemsListMain` declared?

Comment: @degant - I have edited my code above with the information that you have asked for. :) Please refer and give me some help pls.

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga - Please see my code for the declaration as well as my edited code in page.cs for listview binding of view model. Please refer and help. :)

Comment: Try setting the `BindingContext` of the Content Page from the code behind instead of setting for just the `ListView` and also remove the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` from XAML